# breeze.js - help understanding getEntityTypes, IStructuralType, and EntityType casting

Tags: typescript, odata, breeze

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

I'm working in TypeScript and utilizing breeze.EntityManager.metadataStore.getEntityTypes()

This returns breeze.IStructuralType[]

For a particular item in the array, I want the list of navigationProperties.  I can see that this is a property of the object.  I can get to it if I cast the item to a breeze.EntityType

```
(<breeze.EntityType>myItem).navigationProperties
```

1. Are there any other non-EntityType objects that may be returned from getEntityTypes?
2. Is there a better approach than the cast?

Thanks again,
-Mike Graham

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [metadataStore.getEntityTypes()](http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/MetadataStore.html#method_getEntityTypes) method returns all types represented in the metadata, and that includes both `EntityType` and `ComplexType` definitions.

[EntityTypes](http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/EntityType.html) have navigation properties; [ComplexTypes](http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/ComplexType.html) do not.  See [this page in the Breeze docs for more about ComplexTypes](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/complextype-properties).

You can do a cast, but first you should check if `myItem instanceof EntityType`.

Answer (score 1):

If its present on all `breeze.IStructuralType` you could tell typescript about it :

```
declare module breeze{
    interface IStructuralType{
         navigationProperties: any[]; // or what have you
    }
}
```